# A question about probability of set union

Tags: probability

Suppose $\phi$ is a variable, A and B are two events determined by $\phi$, and we have
$$
\forall \phi\in\Phi,\Pr(A(\phi)) \leq \Pr(B(\phi))
$$
Then the inequality
$$
\Pr(\exists \phi,A(\phi)) \leq \Pr(\exists \phi,B(\phi))
$$
does it hold?

It looks right in some case. If we consider $\phi$ to be a person and A, B to be the probabilities for him to win lottery A and lottery B, then in a group of people, the probability of existing someone winning lottery A is smaller than lottery B for sure.

But in general cases, $A(\phi_1)$ and $A(\phi_2)$ may not be independent, so whether this inequality still holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn’t hold. $B(\phi)$ could be the same event for all $\phi\in\Phi$, and the $A(\phi)$ could all be disjoint, so the probabilities of one of them occurring would add up for $A$ but not for $B$.

Comment: you are right. I forgot it...

Comment: I want to ask one thing more...Can I add some conditions to it to make the inequality hold?

Comment: @WuMatt: Yes, you could require that the $B(\phi)$ are disjoint; that would yield

$$
\Pr(\exists \phi,A(\phi))\le\sum_\phi\Pr(A(\phi))\le\sum_\phi\Pr(B(\phi))=\Pr(\exists \phi,B(\phi))\;.
$$

Or that all the $A(\phi)$ are independent and all the $B(\phi)$ are independent; that would yield

$$
\Pr(\exists \phi,A(\phi))=1-\prod_\phi(1-\Pr(A(\phi)))\le1-\prod_\phi(1-\Pr(B(\phi)))=\Pr(\exists \phi,B(\phi))\;.
$$

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you very much!